# Integral $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\sin\big\{ \tfrac{x}{y} \big\}\sin\big\{ \tfrac{y}{x} \big\}dxdy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, fractional-part

This integral was posted on  [AopS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1592457_double_integral) but so far it didn't receive an answer, is there a closed form for this integral? $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\sin\bigg\{ \frac{x}{y} \bigg\}\sin\bigg\{ \frac{y}{x} \bigg\}dxdy$$ I dont have an approach that actually lead to something relevant, but I would love to see a closed form, and I suspect it has a nice one since another similarly looking one can be evaluated to be: $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\bigg\{ \frac{x}{y} \bigg\}\bigg\{ \frac{y}{x} \bigg\}dxdy=1-\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}$$
Also the proposer there mentioned that the integral is interesting I suspected there is one.

Of course there $\{a\}$ denotes the fractional part of $a$.

Comment: could you use the fact that $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}=\frac{x^2+y^2}{xy}$ by using a compound angle formula then see what you have left over. Polar coordinates may also be an option?

Comment: Is anything known about the general case $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\{ \frac{x}{y} \}^n\{ \frac{y}{x} \}^mdxdy$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would get started:
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 \sin\bigg\{\frac{x}{y}\bigg\}\sin\bigg\{\frac{y}{x}\bigg\}dxdy
&=2\int_0^1\int_0^y \sin\bigg\{\frac{x}{y}\bigg\}\sin\bigg\{\frac{y}{x}\bigg\}dxdy\\
&=2\int_0^1\int_0^1 \sin\bigg\{\frac{xy}{y}\bigg\}\sin\bigg\{\frac{y}{xy}\bigg\}ydxdy\\
&=2\int_0^1\int_0^1 y\sin\{x\}\sin\bigg\{\frac{1}{x}\bigg\}dxdy\\
&=2\bigg(\int_0^1 ydy\bigg)\int_0^1 \sin\{x\}\sin\bigg\{\frac{1}{x}\bigg\}dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \sin\{x\}\sin\bigg\{\frac{1}{x}\bigg\}dx\\
&=\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin\{x\}\sin(1/x)}{x^2}dx\\
\end{align}$$
For this integral, I would try converting it to a series... but a closed-form doesn't look too promising.

**EXTRA:** Concerning the comment from @BenedictWilliamJohnIrwin: by employing the above strategy to the integral he proposed, one would obtain
$$\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty \frac{\{x\}^m}{x^{n+2}}dx
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_k^{k+1} \frac{(x-k)^m}{x^{n+2}}dx
\end{align}$$
a general evaluation of this seems unlikely as well, but for certain cases we can evaluate it with ease. For example, consider $m=1$:
$$\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty \frac{\{x\}}{x^{n+2}}dx
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_k^{k+1} \frac{x-k}{x^{n+2}}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{nk^n}-\frac{1}{n(k+1)^n}-\frac{1}{(n+1)k^{n}}+\frac{k}{(n+1)(k+1)^{n+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{n}}-\frac{k}{(k+1)^{n+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{n}}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^{n}}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^{n+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{\zeta(n+1)}{n+1}\\
\end{align}$$
The case for $m=2$ is probably similar, but more messy - perhaps I shall come back and do it later.